# Finding the sum of the odds in between two numbers inclusive

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program to find the sum of the odd numbers in between two inputted numbers, and I would appreciate any feedback. I've been working at this problem for a long time, and I could use some expertise.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("#1: ");
        int num1 = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("#2: ");
        int num2 = s.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i= num1; i<(num2-num1); i++){
            if (i%2 != 0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should test first if the first number is odd or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few simple errors that you can fix in your code here. First, it should not be (num2-num1), but rather just num1. Also, make sure you print your result in the last statement. In contrast, there are many other ways to attack this problem, but if you fix these few issues, your simple method will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would test if `num1` is *even* first, if it is add one to make it *odd* (otherwise, it's already odd). Then increment by `2`, so you know every `i` is *odd*. Next, your loop test should be `<= num2` (not `< num2 - num1`), because you want the range from `num1` to `num2` inclusive. Finally, don't forget to actually print the result. Like,

```
if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
    num1++;
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i+=2) {
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

**Alternatively**, in Java 8+, you might do it with an `IntStream` like

```
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(num1, num2).filter(x -> x % 2 != 0).sum());
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Such a simple solution that I overlooked.!

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply some math instead of looping through all the numbers, which is much more efficient and becomes a constant time algorithm instead of linear time.

To get the sum of the numbers you can multiply the average between both numbers by the count of elements in the range.

If any of both numbers is odd, you can add one, or substract one to reach the first even number in the range, so you calculate from an even to an even number.

Example: from 3 to 12, you will use 4 and 12. Average is 8. And you have (12-4)/2 + 1 = 5 even numbers in the range (the +1 is because it's inclusive range). The sum will be 8*5=40.

Which is true: 4+6+8+10+12 = 40

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
class SumOfOdds
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("#1: ");
            int num1 = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("#2: ");
            int num2 = s.nextInt();
            if (num1 % 2 == 0)
            {
                num1++;
            }
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i+=2)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
}
```

Comment: please add some description to answer for better guide to questioner